# How can I share data between a checkbox/radiogroup and textview in two different activities on eclipse?

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, checkbox

I need to put a list of items in different pages that can be selected through checkboxes and radio buttons and the overall price (addition of each selected item) should be added to the main page.
How can I do this?

here's my code for the main page:

```
package com.example.mcdonalds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MenuPage extends Activity {

private static final String CheckBox = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_page);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_page, menu);
    return true;
}
public void gotoBeefPage(View view) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,BeefPage.class);
    startActivity(intent1);
}
public void gotoChickenPage(View view) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,ChickenPage.class);
    startActivity(intent2);
}
public void gotoKidsMenu(View view) {
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this,KidsMenu.class);
    startActivity(intent3);
}
public void gotoDessertPage(View view) {
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(this,DessertPage.class);
    startActivity(intent4);
}
```

and here's a code for one of the pages that contains checkboxes:

```
package com.example.mcdonalds;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class BeefPage extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_beef_page);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.beef_page, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you're creating an app where the user can go to the different pages, add their dishes (1 beef, 2 chicken, 2 desserts, etc.), and then return to the main page for a summary of their order with a total price?

It seems like you're trying to solve this problem entirely in the view (Activity) code.  The better way to structure it is to have all our activities operate on a shared Data Model object.  You can even have your main activity create the object and then pass it to the individual sub-activities through the Intent.

Modifying your code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class MenuPage extends Activity {

private static final String CheckBox = null;

private Order myOrder = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu_page);
    this.myOrder = new Order();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_page, menu);
    return true;
}
public void gotoBeefPage(View view) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,BeefPage.class);
    intent1.putExtra("Order",this.myOrder);
    startActivityForResult(intent1, requestCode);
}
public void gotoChickenPage(View view) {
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,ChickenPage.class);
    intent2.putExtra("Order",this.myOrder);
    startActivityForResult(intent2, requestCode);
}
public void gotoKidsMenu(View view) {
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(this,KidsMenu.class);
    intent3.putExtra("Order",this.myOrder);
    startActivityForResult(intent3, requestCode);
}
public void gotoDessertPage(View view) {
    Intent intent4 = new Intent(this,DessertPage.class);
    intent4.putExtra("Order",this.myOrder);
    startActivityForResult(intent4, requestCode);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    // Update your local copy of myOrder with what you return in data.
}
```

You will have to make sure that your `Order` object conforms to the [Parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) or [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) interfaces in order to pass it through an intent (I think you can also use Serializable).

Comment: so i just have to modify the code of Main page and the text view will give the price? thank you so much!

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to show the updates to your other pages.  They will have to extract the Bundle from the Intent, update it based on user interactions, and then make sure that it is returned so that the main Activity can use the results.  I only have a moment now, but I can try to post some example code later if you'd like.

Comment: yes please because my code is only displaying errors!

Comment: Is what you posted earlier the entirety of your code for the main and child Activities?  Would you mind posting an example of the errors that you're getting?